# Limiting size of list

Tags: python, list

How to ensure that a list has a certain number of elements only, and extra inputs after that are ignored?

```
 import random
    diceboard = [1,2,0,4,5,0] #for example
    n=0
    def roll():
        dice1=random.randint(1,6)
        dice2=random.randint(1,6)
        dice3=random.randint(1,6)
        dice4=random.randint(1,6)
        dice5=random.randint(1,6)
        dice6=random.randint(1,6)
        return [dice1,dice2,dice3,dice4,dice5,dice6]
    while diceboard.index!=0: #this basically means that per each element 
    that does not have a value of zero(pls correct my code)
        n=n+1
    newroll=roll()
    newroll=newroll.split(None, n)[:n] #this limits the size of the list 
    print(newroll)
```

Comment: What are the meaning of the values in diceboard? I understand you're trying to filter non-zero values in that list... but what is the difference between 1, 2, 4, 5... ? Aslo I don't understand the desired output, can you provide a specific example?

Comment: I'm sorry but it's unclear what you're asking... I don't know what is diceboard.index...

Comment: Can you explain why this is a requirement for the code you show? and also what this code is supposed to do? It's not clear and it sounds to me like you have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If we can fully understand your problem we may be able to offer a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interpretation of what I understood from your question:

https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/0893e2af-726d-4fb3-9155-d83ecc5bbd55/

```
import random
diceboard = [1,2,0,4,5,0] #for example
def roll():
    return list(map(
        lambda x: random.randint(1,6),
        range(len(diceboard))
    ))

n=0
#this basically means that per each element 
#that does not have a value of zero(pls correct my code)
non_zero_diceboard = [d for d in diceboard if d > 0]
for i in range(len(non_zero_diceboard)):
    n=n+1
    newroll=roll()
    newroll=newroll[:n] #this limits the size of the list 
    print(newroll)
```